# Jquery: run a method on certain elements but not others

Tags: jquery, element

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to run a method on certain elements/nodetypes but not others.

For instance here's some HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="subparent">Changing Text
        <div class="no-change">Changing Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="subparent">Changing Text</div>
        <div class="child">Changing Text
            <div class="no-change">Changing Text</div>
        </div>
    <div class="subparent">Changing Text</div>
</div>
```

My method is something like this:

```
jQuery.fn.changingtext = function(expr) {
    return this.each(function() {
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML
        .replace(/Changing Text/ig, "Edited!")
    });
};
```

Now I want to change the text of everything except what's in div.no-change. The end result should be something like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="subparent">Edited!
        <div class="no-change">Changing Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="subparent">Edited!</div>
        <div class="child">Edited!
            <div class="no-change">Changing Text</div>
        </div>
    <div class="subparent">Edited!</div>
</div>
```

I don't know of any way to select a parent without also running the method on its child. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Here is using Paulo's code and not working:
http://jsbin.com/usaxa

Edit@Jeff Meatball Yang:
Hi, using your inplace replacement it outputs as text rather than html:
http://jsbin.com/idina

I also wasn't able to get the other methods working:
http://jsbin.com/aguca

Could you provide an example please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery.fn.changingtext = function(expr) {
    return this.each(function() {
      // filter for text node
      var nodes = $(this).contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3); });

      // or do in-place editing
      for(var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
        nodes[i].nodeValue = nodes[i].nodeValue.replace(/Changing Text/ig, "Edited!");
      }
    });
};

// prove that no change is still white
$("#parent div.no-change").css("color", "white");

// change text, then make it red using jQuery
$("#parent div:not(.no-change)").changingtext().css("color", "red");
```

The end result is already HTML.  So, you will be able to chain other jQuery functions after the plugin call.  See my edit.

---

instead of setting the text node value (nodes[i].nodeValue), you can remove it and append a DIV after it.  Instead of using a for loop and replacing the text, you can remove the for loop and use jQuery's built-in functions:

```
jQuery.fn.changingtext = function(expr) {
    return this.each(function() {
      // filter for text node
      var nodes = $(this).contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3); });

      // you can replace the text nodes:
      // insert a DIV after each one, 
      // then remove it from the DOM
      nodes.after("<div>Edited!</div>").remove();
    });
};
```

This is documented in the jQuery Docs (http://docs.jquery.com) on Manipulation and Traversing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is great! It comes out as a text node, how can I make the end result HTML?

Thanks!

Comment: The end result is already HTML.  So, you will be able to chain other jQuery functions after the plugin call.

Comment: Hi thanks, sorry I don't mean the parent element. I mean the replaced node type. For instance what if my replacement was /Changing (Text)/g, "<div id="$1">Edited</div>". How could I make that into HTML?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I don't understand your instructions for replacing the textnode so that it will become HTML. Please see my edit.

Comment: Mark, I've tried to clarify - see the second piece of code with my latest edit.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not really sure why you're writing a plugin to do this. This would find all the `<div>` elements inside #parent, filter out those that don't have the class of `.no-change`, and edit the text contents of them:

```
$('#parent').find('div').not('.no-change').text('Edited!');
```

Which could also be written as:

```
$('#parent div:not(.no-change)').text('Edited!');
```

jQuery is very good at working on set of elements, you don't have to loop through them and such.

**EDIT**:

This should work to take account CMS's good observation:

```
$('#parent').find('div').not('.no-change').each(function() {
    $(this).contents().not('*').eq(0).replaceWith('Whatever');    
});
```

Comment: +1 But a problem still, the divs are nested, for example, the second div (class 'subparent') he is trying to change only the text node ('Changing Text') and that div has a 'no-change' div nested that will be replaced by the 'text' function, actually both 'no-change' divs are nested inside of divs that will change.

Comment: Hi, I don't believe your code works:

http://jsbin.com/usaxa

The reason why I'm using a plugin is because the replacement is actually dozens of replacements and I need to run it in many different places.

Thanks again though!

Comment: The code does work and is tested, your translation of it doesn't work. You seem to already have found a solution that helps you, though, so I won't bother posting how to do it the way you want it...

Comment: Hi, please do! I'm sure your solution will be both helpful and educational.

Comment: A year later I come back browsing and I understand why you put this answer. You're selecting specific divs and replacing them with 'Whatever', whereas I actually need to use regex on the innerHTML because my real replacements are more complicated.